# Compilation with xelatex stops indefinitely when using tcbitemize

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox

First of all, in the following input file I use Kanji Stroke Order fonts. Therefore, please kindly download the font from this [site (click)](http://www.nihilist.org.uk/).

The real objective is to write an enumerated list of Japanese sentences. The occurences of Kanji phrases marked with `\phrase` (in each sentences) will be rendered in two different places.

- First, they will be rendered in `\section{Sentences}` as `\item` of `enumerate` environment. Only Chinese characters and its furigana will be rendered using normal fonts. In the input file, I only need to prepare this section.
- Second, they will be automatically rendered in `\section{Vocabularies}` as `tcbitem` of `tcbitemize` environment. Chinese characters with stroke order (using Kanji Stroke Order font), its furigana, and its meaning are rendered here. In the input file, I don't need to prepare this section. It means that the phrases defined in `\section{Sentences}` are reused here automatically.

In this way, the readers of my document can refer to the Kanji phrases if they want to know how to hand write the Kanji in question and what their meaning are.

Let me divide the development into several phases because in each phases I might have problems.

## Phase 1

In this phase, I want to make sure I can compile the document without errors with `xelatex`. Rendering `\section{Vocabularies}` automatically has not been implemented yet. That is why in the following MWE I repeat the phrase `彼` twice.  In the subsequent phases, I will try to make `\phrase` only prepared in `\section{Sentences}` and reused in `\section{Vocabularies}`.

Enabling `tcbitemize` makes the compilation stop indefinitely. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf} % For furigana and other Japanese characters
\newCJKfontfamily\strokefont{KanjiStrokeOrders_v3.001.ttf} % For stroke order

\usepackage{ruby}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\def\GlobalSettings{%
    \renewcommand\rubysep{0pt}%
    \renewcommand\rubysize{0.4}%
    \let\oldruby\ruby%
    \renewcommand\ruby[2]{\oldruby{##1}{\textcolor{Red}{##2}}}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\GlobalSettings}

\def\LocalSettings{%
    \renewcommand\rubysep{1ex}%
    \renewcommand\rubysize{.3}%
    \let\oldruby\ruby%
    \renewcommand\ruby[2]{\oldruby{\fontsize{65}{0}\selectfont\strokefont##1}{\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont\textcolor{Red}{##2}}}%
}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\def\phrase[#1]#2{\LocalSettings\tcbitem {\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont#1\par}\vspace{15pt}\textcolor{Cyan}{\bfseries#2}}


\begin{document}

\section{Sentences}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \ruby{彼}{かれ}は目が大きい。
\end{enumerate}


\section{Vocabularies}

\newgeometry{margin=2mm}

% tcbitemize makes the compilation stops!

%\begin{tcbitemize}[%
        %raster height=\textheight,
        %raster columns=2,
        %raster rows=5,
        %size=fbox,
        %sharp corners,
        %halign=flush center,
        %valign=center,
        %boxrule=2pt,   % line width
        %raster column skip=-2pt,   % negative line width
        %raster row skip=-2pt,  % negative line width
        %colframe=Red,
        %colback=White,
%]%
%\phrase[\ruby{彼}{かれ}]{he}
%\end{tcbitemize}

test
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it happen with other fonts too or when compiling with luatex?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I have not tested it with luatex. But with other fonts, the compilation still stops.

Comment: Using a non-CJK font (I can't test it with CJK, sorry), say the standard LaTeX fonts will show if the trouble is elsewhere

Comment: What does `ruby` package do? Do I need to have `ruby` installed?

Comment: I can't test with CJK, but I guess nesting `\tcbitem` into `\phrase` gives the problem. I would use a `tcbraster` instead of the specialized `tcbitemize`. Then, inside `\phrase`, you can use a `tcolorbox` instead of `\tcbitem`. That should work better.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: `\ruby` is used to show furigana stacked on the top of the modified Kanji.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: I found that the code runs into a loop due to the `\localsettings`

Comment: The `\let\oldruby\ruby` in the `\localsettings` isn't healthy. I suspect that this is global there, so it's circular redefinition

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah, I see. Nevertheless, since `\tcbitem` closes an environment and opens another one, I would not use it in a macro like `\phrase`.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Ok, I'll answer the main cause, you answer the `tcbraster` improvement? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK, I added the `tcbraster` alternative. But your code with `\tcbitem` runs without problems :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks. Always nice to your package in action!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main cause is the `\let\oldruby\ruby` setting in `\localsettings`

(Sorry, I had to comment some font settings)

`\let\oldruby\ruby` in the outer settings (`\GlobalSettings`) is alright, but `\let\oldruby\ruby` in the `\LocalSettings` command will lead to a vicious circle, i.e. a loop and `TeX` (regardless xelatex/lualatex/pdflatex` will fail.

As far as I understand the original `\ruby` command as provided by the `ruby` package is to be used, so store this in `\veryoldruby` and all should be ok.

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

    \usepackage{xeCJK}
%    \setmainfont{Cambria}
    \setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf} % For furigana and other Japanese characters
    \newCJKfontfamily\strokefont{KanjiStrokeOrders_v3.001.ttf} % For stroke order

    \usepackage{ruby}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

    \let\veryoldruby\ruby%    

    \def\GlobalSettings{%
        \renewcommand\rubysep{0pt}%
        \renewcommand\rubysize{0.4}%
        \let\oldruby\ruby%
        \renewcommand\ruby[2]{\veryoldruby{##1}{\textcolor{Red}{##2}}}%
    }
    \AtBeginDocument{\GlobalSettings}

    \def\LocalSettings{%
        \renewcommand\rubysep{1ex}%
        \renewcommand\rubysize{.3}%
%       \let\oldruby\ruby%
        \renewcommand\ruby[2]{\veryoldruby{\fontsize{65}{0}\selectfont ##1}{\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont\textcolor{Red}{##2}}}%
%       \renewcommand\ruby[2]{\veryoldruby{\fontsize{65}{0}\selectfont\strokefont##1}{\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont\textcolor{Red}{##2}}}%
    }

    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \def\phrase[#1]#2{\LocalSettings\tcbitem {\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont#1\par}\vspace{15pt}\textcolor{Cyan}{\bfseries#2}}


    \begin{document}

    \section{Sentences}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \ruby{foo}{bar} ... foobar%\ruby{彼}{かれ}は目が大きい。
    \end{enumerate}


    \section{Vocabularies}

    \newgeometry{margin=2mm}

    % tcbitemize makes the compilation stops!

    \begin{tcbitemize}[%
            raster height=\textheight,
            raster columns=2,
            raster rows=5,
            size=fbox,
            sharp corners,
            halign=flush center,
            valign=center,
            boxrule=2pt,    % line width
            raster column skip=-2pt,    % negative line width
            raster row skip=-2pt,   % negative line width
            colframe=Red,
            colback=White,
    ]%
%    \phrase[\ruby{彼}{かれ}]{he}
    \phrase[\ruby{foo}{bar}]{he}
    \end{tcbitemize}

%    test
    \restoregeometry
    \end{document}
```

**T. F. Sturm will do the improvement of the `tcbitem` code ;-)**

Comment: I think removing `\let\oldruby\ruby` from `LocalSettings` in my MWE is the simplest solution. :-)

Comment: @kissmyarmpit: Yes and no: It depends on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 3):

Christian Hupfer already did the main job in eliminating the infinite loop. Now, the code is running . As an add-on, I would replace the `tcbitemize` environment by a `tcbraster` environment for this application here. The reason is that `\tcbitem` is a tricky macro which closes and opens environments and **may** cause problems when embedded inside other macros like the `\phrase` from the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
%    \setmainfont{Cambria}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf} % For furigana and other Japanese characters
\newCJKfontfamily\strokefont{KanjiStrokeOrders_v3.001.ttf} % For stroke order

\usepackage{ruby}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\let\veryoldruby\ruby%

\def\GlobalSettings{%
    \renewcommand\rubysep{0pt}%
    \renewcommand\rubysize{0.4}%
    \let\oldruby\ruby%
    \renewcommand\ruby[2]{\veryoldruby{##1}{\textcolor{Red}{##2}}}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\GlobalSettings}

\def\LocalSettings{%
    \renewcommand\rubysep{1ex}%
    \renewcommand\rubysize{.3}%
%       \let\oldruby\ruby%
    \renewcommand\ruby[2]{\veryoldruby{\fontsize{65}{0}\selectfont ##1}{\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont\textcolor{Red}{##2}}}%
%       \renewcommand\ruby[2]{\veryoldruby{\fontsize{65}{0}\selectfont\strokefont##1}{\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont\textcolor{Red}{##2}}}%
}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\def\phrase[#1]#2{\begin{tcolorbox}\LocalSettings{\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont#1\par}\vspace{15pt}\textcolor{Cyan}{\bfseries#2}\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}

\section{Sentences}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \ruby{foo}{bar} ... foobar%\ruby{彼}{かれ}は目が大きい。
\end{enumerate}


\section{Vocabularies}

\newgeometry{margin=2mm}

\begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster height=\textheight,
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=5,
        size=fbox,
        sharp corners,
        halign=flush center,
        valign=center,
        boxrule=2pt,    % line width
        raster column skip=-2pt,    % negative line width
        raster row skip=-2pt,   % negative line width
        colframe=Red,
        colback=White,
]%
\phrase[\ruby{彼}{かれ}]{he}
\phrase[\ruby{彼}{かれ}]{he}
\phrase[\ruby{彼}{かれ}]{he}
\phrase[\ruby{彼}{かれ}]{he}
\phrase[\ruby{foo}{bar}]{he}
\end{tcbraster}

%    test
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```